# How to use "Remote URL" option in Alloed values options in RUNDECK?

Tags: rundeck

I have list of data in remote location at path .... \files\allversions.text and need to read it and push data to "Rundeck" options "List" field , to show on JOB UI. Some one help me, how to implemen this scenario , using the "Remote URL"  option or else let me know if we have any other way.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eU4CU.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eU4CU.png)

Fastest response would be highly appreciated, thnak you,
Dev G

Answer (score 0):

1. keep in mind that the remote options need a [specific JSON format](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/job-options.html#json-format) as follows:

```json
[
  {"name":"X Label", "value":"x value"},
  {"name":"Y Label", "value":"y value"},
  {"name":"A Label", "value":"a value"}
]
```

2. To use the JSON as a remote option URL, use the `file:` format, for example: `file:/Users/myuser/myopts.json`. To use only the allowed values defined in the JSON file: edit your job, edit your option, scroll down, and then select the "Enforced from Allowed Values" radio button (on the "Restrictions" [section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbYU4.jpg)).

Check the result [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxcuI.jpg).

I left a job definition example for testing (check [here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/creating-jobs.html#importing-job-definitions) to learn how to import job definitions to your Rundeck instance).

```yaml
- defaultTab: nodes
  description: ''
  executionEnabled: true
  id: d46fe6e8-5dfe-4f7c-9e70-d9791cb3c328
  loglevel: INFO
  name: RemoteOptionJSON
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  options:
  - enforced: true
    name: myopts
    valuesUrl: file:/Users/myuser/myopts.json
  plugins:
    ExecutionLifecycle: null
  scheduleEnabled: true
  sequence:
    commands:
    - exec: echo ${option.myopts}
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: node-first
  uuid: d46fe6e8-5dfe-4f7c-9e70-d9791cb3c328
```